# How do I prevent ServiceStack Razor from encoding my HTML?

Tags: razor, servicestack

Inside of my View page I have the following line:

```
@Model.RenderedMarkdown
```

RenderedMarkdown is generated with the following:

```
var renderer = new MarkdownSharp.Markdown();
return renderer.Transform(Markdown);
```

Now for this example, let's just say that Markdown was this:

```
###test
```

which will change into this:

```
<h3>test</h3>
```

However what is being rendered on my page is this:

```
&lt;h3&gt;test&lt;/h3&gt;
```

Is there a setting somewhere to turn off this automatic encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.Raw("<h3>test</h3>")
```

Put your variable to `Raw` helper.

Something like this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model)
```

**Added:**

Thanks to **mythz** and his comment:

`There is also an T.AsRaw() extension method. Which basically just wraps the string into a MvcHtmlString which doesn't get escaped.`

Comment: Unfortunately that resulted in the same thing, I think ServiceStack is automatically changing the content before it hits the View page.

Comment: @JustinN Set brake point in action or use `@Html.TextAreaFor()` to view your content.

Comment: @JustinN Interesting question about `MarkdownSharp`: [Why isn't MarkdownSharp encoding my HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864255/why-isnt-markdownsharp-encoding-my-html)

Comment: I'll give that a go this evening, this specific bit of code is on my laptop which I didn't bring to the office today. Interesting read though, and might be the fix as I did have the code prefixed with some text on the same line (simply for testing purposes)

Comment: There is also an `T.AsRaw()` extension method. Which basically just wraps the string into a **MvcHtmlString** which doesn't get escaped. @webdeveloper can you update your answer to include this?

Comment: @mythz Of course, could you provide link to msdn with example? I had never used this extension. Thanks!

Comment: @webdeveloper it's an extension inside ServiceStack - mythz created ServiceStack. AsRaw() worked! The line breaks however did not... update your answer and I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @JustinN Thanks, I understand now. Found his answer with example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586343/servicestack-net-mini-profiler-in-razor-view